# Maximize, minimize interpretation problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this:

$$
f(x,y,z)=x+y+z
$$

Decide the maximum and minimum value on the intersecting curve:

$$
h(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2+z^2-2=0
$$

$$
g(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2-z=0
$$

Given this, we know that the gradients give us a plane where the maximum/minimum is when the determinant of these gradients equal zero.

After calculating the determinant I end up with:

$$
2y(z+1)=2x(z+1)
$$

And after solving, substituting I have the correct maximum and minimum according to Wolfram Alpha.

The only problem, I have not examined when z=-1, and here I'm confused, because z=-1 give us that x and y can be whatever they want, and the function does not have max or min.

Am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: If you plug in z=-1, then g and h simplify to $x^2+y^2=1$ as a constraint since those equations still have to hold, no?

Comment: I calculated on it, and the minimum value I get from there is lower than the one Wolfram Alpha says, so something is wrong...

Comment: What were the computed values and what were x,y, and z for those cases?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says: (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2), 1)=sqrt(2)+1 and (-1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2), 1)=1-sqrt(2)

Comment: @JulianAssange I solved the problem as regular optimization. z=-1 is no special point. Why you think -1 is special?

Comment: Becuase it gives me f(-1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2), -1), and that is smaller than the minimum Wolfram gives me? Or am I wrong somewhere? How do you solve it then?

Comment: @JulianAssange your solution set is not correct. If you want I can post you the correct one.

Comment: @AnilBaseski: Yes, thanks. I have struggled with this for a while now, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it as a regular optimization problem and construct the Lagrangian such as
$$L=x+y+z+\lambda_1(x^2+y^2+z^2-2)+\lambda_2(x^2+y^2-z)$$
The first order conditions are
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=1+2x\lambda_1+2x\lambda_2=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=1+2y\lambda_1+2y\lambda_2=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=1+2z\lambda_1-\lambda_2=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=x^2+y^2+z^2-2=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=x^2+y^2-z=0$$
If you solve the system (it takes some time) feasible sets are (ignoring imaginary ones)
$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad z=1\quad \lambda_1=\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{6}\quad \lambda_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad z=1\quad \lambda_1=\frac{-\sqrt{2}-2}{6}\quad \lambda_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Comment: I see, you are doing it in a different way, I'm using another determinant approach. Interesting though.